# How to get the *correct* computer name in .NET/Mono cross platform

Tags: .net, mono

I'm on OSX, My computer's name is "systemg"

[image: systemg]

Other answers on SO say I should check `System.Environment.MachineName` but that **DOES NOT WORK**.

```
 Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.MachineName);
```

outputs

```
 systemg.local
```

That is not the correct computer name.

Some other answer said `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` so

```
 Console.WriteLine("[" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + "]");
```

outputs

```
 [176.230.18.213.client.dyn.somemain.com: ]
```

Also not my computer's name

Is there a way to get the correct computer name across platforms in .NET/Mono

Comment: On OS-X the `.local` is a Bonjour host name and thus is the 'correct' name, this of course can change based upon it belonging only to a disconnected/DNS-less Bonjour style network which is the case for your example case. Join a domain, lan, etc... and it will become `.private` or `.lan` or ... and thus the DNS-based host name will change. If you want the user entered `Computer sharing name` and not its DNS name, capture the output from `scutil --get ComputerName` or parse the `System.Environment.MachineName` based upon network status

Comment: "correct" is in the eye of the beholder. I'm looking for the name the user assigned to the machine, not some auto generated name based on random network conditions. Parsing won't help. The user's machine might be called "My Machine" but `System.Environment.MachineName` will return "My-Machine" with no way for me to know the user didn't enter a `-`.  `scutil` works but that's not .NET/Mono nor cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

#### Per Microsoft's description of the `MachineName` property:

`System.Environment.MachineName`

> Gets the NetBIOS name of this local computer.

#### Per Microsoft's reference source:

In the case of the .Net reference source, the `gethostname` ([Win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx)) that is called by the C# code to return this property.

> The form of the host name is dependent on the Windows Sockets provider—it can be a **simple host name**, or it can be a **fully qualified domain name**. However, it is guaranteed that the name returned will be successfully parsed by gethostbyname and WSAAsyncGetHostByName.

#### Mono:

Mono uses `gethostname` in the **same manner** that MS's reference source does, thus the value you are seeing is NOT controlled by the System's `corlib` code, but by the OS's native networking stack implementation and it as 'correct' as it gets...

For Linux (via Posix, OpenGroup, 4.2BSD) other than the character length and perms access check, the actual definition is fairly generic:

> The gethostname() function shall return the standard host name for the current machine

For OS-X, they follow the Posix std, and

> The hostname that the hostname command or the gethostname function return is determined by the name set in the 'Sharing Preference' pane. If this name contains a space, you may get only the leading part of the name, upto but not including the first space.

Also remember that OS-X has, besides the Bonjour-based sharing name, a `LocalHostName`, `HostName` and a `ComputerName` ;-) but only the Bonjour based one is returned by `gethostname`.